# window.history.pushState to localhost/MySite

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `pushState` to change to URL to manipulate the browser address bar while clicking on an image in my website.

how can I change it back to the homepage when working with on development environment.
for example: my address bar has this URL: **http://localhost/MySite**
after clicking on a picture I'm changing the address bar to: **http://localhost/MySite/pic/123**
with window.history.pushState.

The problem is - On development environment, I cant use

```
window.history.pushState(obj, title , '/');
```

since the slash ('/') takes me to **http://localhost/**.

I tried "../" instead but it still doesn't work
and window.history.back() neither.

Any advice?

Comment: How can the browser know that your "root" is `/MySite/`? To test different sites, I'd advise to use different ports. Or, when you just want a quick solution, use `.htaccess` to rewrite the root to `MySite`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be more elegant way. i solved it out by changing the root to /MySite/ in the dev environment.

Comment: I would also say, try to adjust a .htaccess with mod_rewrite. Or add a "?" before the "/" in development. Than you stay in your directory and it also changes the state.

Answer (score 1):

Use location.pathname and a regular expression or something to get the base path

```
var viewingImagePattern = /\/pic\/\d+$/;
var rootPath = location.pathname.replace(viewingImagePattern, "/");
window.history.pushState(obj, title , rootPath);
```